# English grammar about get

Tags: verbs

Please help me to complete this sentence:

> This is a great track. It will get everybody _______.

Which one is better: **dance** or **dancing**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either "dancing" or "to dance", but the first one sounds a bit less manipulative (as if everyone is doing it out of excitement, not because they are expected to).

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of words in English that "take" other words as "parameters."  Many English verbs take objects, for example, but there's other possibilities.

> I ate the food (*The food* is an object of *ate*. *I ate X* - X would be the object.)
>
> The dog is brown (*brown* is a subject complement of *dog*.)
>
> Martha is a dancer (*a dancer* is a "predicate nominative" of *Martha*)

The plain/present-tense form of a verb cannot ever be "taken" by another word by itself, unless:

- *-ing* is tacked on to it,
- *to* is in front it,
- a relative pronoun is in front of it (words like *who*, *which*)
- something happens in the sentence where you can start the "Subject-Verb-Etc" pattern over again.

> It will get everybody to dance.
>
> It will get everybody who dances to have fun.
>
> It will get everybody dancing.
>
> We dance until the night falls.